# How to choose the default (or any) CKEditor toolbar?

Tags: wysiwyg

OK, I'm obviously missing something.  I've installed CKEditor into a D7 site, and all's well.  The only problem is I can't figure out how to specify the toolbar that will come up by default in CKEditor-enabled fields.  I've defined a new toolbar in .../ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.config.js, but I haven't found any place in the site's config options (or the code, for that matter) that let me say that I want CKEditor to put up this particular toolbar.  For that matter, I don't see any way to be able to choose the other toolbars in ckeditor.config.js (like DrupalAdvanced and DrupalFull).  Any clarification out there?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured this out: See http://drupal.org/node/1434814#comment-5583354 for the solution.  The most important bits are:

- If you're just using the basic CKEditor module, ckeditor.config.js is completely irrelevant to getting your toolbar set up. Ignore it.
- CKEditor toolbars are associated with text formats, like "Filtered HTML" or "Full HTML" (or, presumably, other text formats you might define). Each text format can be connected to exactly one toolbar; when a textbox with that text format appears, its toolbar will be presented.